# Mule datamapper DateTime conversion gives unparsable date for String 'yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ'

Tags: datetime, mule, mule-studio, mule-el, mule-component

I have a request xml having a dateTime string as '2014-09-23T00:00:00.000+01:00' and I am mapping it to an element of type xs:dateTime using Mule 3.5 datamapper.
The Datamapper internally applies str2Calendar(Str,Str) function or mapping.
So I edited the script to look like:

```
output.dateAndTimeString = str2calendar(input.dateAndTime, "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");
```

The error in log is:

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date "2014-09-23T00:00:00.000+01:00"
```

Is anything wrong with Mule data-mapper or with my conversion technique?

Answer (score 1):

You can drop the 'Z' and use the overloaded str2calendar to set the default timezone. This example uses the MEL expression to get the servers timezone:

output.dateAndTimeString = str2calendar(input.dateAndTime, "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS", server.timeZone);

Comment: But after mapping the result has a Z in place of +01:00 that further not recognized as valid dateTime by a third party web service.

Comment: Did you add the overloaded timezone param?

Comment: I tried like TimeZone.getTimezone('UTC') but error was like Unrecognized component Timezone.